# Java ArrayList loop issues

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am programming a monopoly-esque game with java on eclipse.
I am currently working on a method that allows players to loop through their own squares and choose which one to develop.

```
for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < currentPlayer.getOwnedSquares().size(); loop2++) {

    count++;

    System.out.println("Would you like to develop this property " + count + ". " 
    + currentPlayer.getOwnedSquares().get(loop2).getName() + " (y/n)");

    propertyChoice = scanner.nextLine();

    if (propertyChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            break;
        }else if (propertyChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

            continue;
        }
    }
System.out.println("Please choose a development option");
System.out.println("1.Buy a start-up");
System.out.println("2.Buy a global corporation");
int option = scanner.nextInt();
```

I am unable to get the loop to present only one owned square at a time so the player can choose to select y/n for which one the want to develop. If the player was to pick "N" The loop would then present the next owned property in the array and the player would make another decision and so on..
If the player was to pick "Y" then the loop would break and move on the development options for the chosen owned square.

Any advice on how to realise this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: Which is exactly the problem you are having? Seems like a good starting point to me.

Comment: It's showing all the owned properties at once rather than one at a time, so the player is unable to cycle through the options

Comment: I would like it to display the first owedproperty at loop2 and then depending on the y/n choice the next one. Currently its printing out all of them at once, I can't really figure out why

Comment: The code looks fine! Cant seem to understand why you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the check for user input out of the loop, so the algorithm would look like this:

1. Print all the owned squares in a loop.
2. Ask user (outside the loop) which square he wants to develop. For example, a user can simply provide a positional number of a square which you can get by

   ```
   currentPlayer.getOwnedSquares().get(Integer.valueOf(userInput));
   ```
3. Do whatever you need with selected square.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the code to test, and it works as you want. I think there is something else problematic which you haven't shared.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;
        String propertyChoice;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < 5; loop2++) {

            count++;

            System.out.println("Would you like to develop this property " + count
                     + " (y/n)");

            propertyChoice = scanner.nextLine();

            if (propertyChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                break;
            }else if (propertyChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please choose a development option");
        System.out.println("1.Buy a start-up");
        System.out.println("2.Buy a global corporation");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Would you like to develop this property 1 (y/n)
n
Would you like to develop this property 2 (y/n)
n
Would you like to develop this property 3 (y/n)
y
Please choose a development option
1.Buy a start-up
2.Buy a global corporation

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I will look into this further and try and figure what else in the code could be causing the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `scanner.nextLine();` inmediately before `propertyChoice = scanner.nextLine();`

Edit: if this doesn't work, notice that the `else` has no brackets surrounding the second `if` block. I don't know if this will work as I do not see the classes you are refering to and cannot say there is the error. The code you've shown doesn't seem to have any other issue.

Comment: dont know about `else if` ?

Comment: I've always surrounded the if with brackets so nah.

Comment: You might wanna look at `else if` too, in that case. Its pretty basic.